# Inheritance Fundamentals

Tags: oop, inheritance

```
class Base
{

}

class Derive:Base
{

}

Base b=new Derive();
```

The above code works,but why we are able to create a Object of Derive Class and assigning it to Base Class reference.
Also,the object variable 'b' will be able to access all non private variable and methods of Class Base,even though it is referencing Derive Class.
What makes this possible,why the object variable 'b' which is referencing Derive Object is able to access the Base Class and not the Derive Class.

Comment: I don't think the code will work, they don't even compile.

Answer (score 3):

The theory allowing the above code to work is called the [**substitution principle**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle): When `Derived` is a subtype of `Base`, this forms a "is-a" relationship. The substitution principle postulates that wherever an instance of `Base` is expected, it can be substituted by an instance of `Derived`.

The reason you cannot access the properties and methods of the `Derive` class later on is that (at least to a computer) there is no indication whatsoever that a variable of type `Base` contains an instance of type `Derive` which would allow access to these properties/methods. If you take another class `DerivedToo : Base` which has other methods than `Derive` you quickly see how the program could break if you assumed the `Base` variable to hold a `Derive` instance.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is polymorhism question rather than inheritance.

One of the key features of derived classes is that a pointer to a derived class is type-compatible with a pointer to its base class. Using polymorphism you can take advantage of this feature.

Polymorhism allows you to invoke derived class methods through a base class reference during run-time. This is handy when you need to assign a group of objects to an array and then invoke each of their methods. They won't necessarily have to be the same object type. However, if they're related by inheritance, you can add them to the array as the inherited type.